# Angular 2: How to call a method from another component

Tags: angular, methods, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a button in my html template that calls a method, but this method is not found in its own component. It's found in another component. What should I do?

HTML template:

```
<button class="ui button basic medium" (click)="showConfirmation()">Delete</button>
```

The `showConfirmation()` method is found in `dialog-box.component.ts`

In my `showConfirmation()`, I have a jQuery that allows viewing of a Semantic-UI modal

```
showConfirmation(show: boolean){
      $('.ui.small.modal').modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an entire chapter of the Angular documentation aimed to answer this question. You can find it here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

The key options are:

- Pass data from parent to child with input binding
- Intercept input property changes with a setter
- Intercept input property changes with ngOnChanges()
- Parent listens for child event
- Parent interacts with child via local variable
- Parent calls an @ViewChild()
- Components communicate via a service

As mentioned in the text of these, all but the last assume that the two components have a parent/child relationship meaning that one of the components is nested within the other component.

Answer (score 2):

One approach, in a parent-child relationship, would be to have the parent listen for an event on the child. The child needs an output: `@Output() onShowConfirmation = new EventEmitter<boolean>();` and a function that emits an event on it like so:

```
showConfirmation(show: boolean) {
    this.onShowConfirmation.emit(show);
    this.confirmationShown = true;
}
```

Then, in the parent template, bind a function in the parent component to the output on the child component:

```
<confirmation-widget>
    (onShowConfirmation)="onShowConfirmation($event)">
</confirmation-widget>
```

This is just a modified version of the example in the docs linked below.

Alternatively, you can use a service to coordinate the two components. It really depends on their relationship. Take a look at the Angular docs here to see what would be the best approach given your configuration:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Comment: Is there a way for me to open a modal through service? Since it won't read the showConfirmation() method

Comment: I actually don't think you should make a service to coordinate them unless you have delete buttons in multiple sections or components of your application. I'd be happy to help fix your actual code if you can make a plunker or example of your problem. In fact if all you need is a simple confirmation box, I'd recommend you look at something like https://github.com/toverux/ngsweetalert2.

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewChild decorator from angular core

```
 @ViewChild(dialogComponent)
  private localDialog: dialogComponent

showConfirmation() {

this.localDialog.showConfirmation();
}
```

you can get more details [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)

Comment: where should I put this? In the present component?

Comment: It says "cannot find name "ViewChild""

Comment: you can import it from import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146811/discussion-between-char-and-fastastortoise).